# SPRING MVC DateTimeFormat error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, datetime-format

Im trying to make a website using Spring + Angular JS and my current problem is i used POSTMAN to post a JSON statement as below:

```
{
    "id": 12345,
    "checkin" : "2017-03-01",
    "checkout" : "2017-03-05"
}
```

and then this error pops up:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHyC7.png)

"Type definition error: [simple type, class java.time.LocalDate]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2017-03-01')"

Resource Code:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ReservationResponse> createReservation(
        @RequestBody
        ReservationRequest reservationRequest){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ReservationResponse(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Model Code:

```
public class ReservationRequest {
    private Long id;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate checkin;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate checkout;}
```

APIConfig Code:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModules(new JavaTimeModule());
    return new ObjectMapper();
}
```

Application Properties:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
```

Build Gradle:

```
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.8.7'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49968854/springboot-testresttemplate-and-localdatetime-not-working

Comment: You are using Spring Boot so you don't need the explicitly configured `ObjectMapper`. Just register the `JavaTImeModule` as an `@Bean` instead. If you are using Spring Boot 2 you don't even need to do that as Spring 5 automatically registers the `JavaTImeModule` when present.

Comment: Wow thanks!. i just removed the object mapper and it worked! i appreciate your help sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We also faced the same issue and after defining a converter it worked fine. You can add below code in the application and it should work fine. You can change the date format as per your need.

```
@Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter customJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
       MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
       ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
          objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
          objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_KEYS_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
          objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
          objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a"));
      jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

      return jsonConverter;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working through the same tutorial and encountered the same problem. What made my code work was to change the return value of the `objectMapper()` method in API Config Code from `new ObjectMapper()` to `objectMapper`.