# Configure JavaTimeModule in ObjectMapper globally instead of using @datetimeformat

Tags: java, spring-boot, objectmapper

Hi I try to create a controller which will accept request-parameter as LocalDateTime.

```
ex: /api/actions?page=0&size=10&from=2018-05-02T20:20:20&to=2018-06-02T20:20:20
```

at controller if I using code bellow it work:

```
@RequestParam(value = "from")
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
                LocalDateTime from,
        @RequestParam(value = "to")
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
                LocalDateTime to
```

But I want to move @DateTimeFormat to globally configuration, and I choose ObjectMapper:

I create a bean in configuration:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
    javaTimeModule.addSerializer(
            LocalDateTime.class,
            new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimeFormat)));
    objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

And try

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.createXmlMapper(false).build();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
    javaTimeModule.addSerializer(
            LocalDateTime.class,
            new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimeFormat)));
    objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

This is dateTimeFormat value: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS

Both of 2 ways above are not working, It said:

class org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam java.time.LocalDateTime] for value '2018-05-02T20:20:20'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2018-05-02T20:20:20]

My jackson version:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Am I missing something?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Check this answer. I already answered solution in other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50128685/6703392

Comment: It doesn't use Jackson so configuring that won't do anything.

Comment: Problem is I pass LocalDateTime at requestParam, but I using ObjectMapper which only work with request's body.

And to resolve my issue I create new component LocalDateTimeConverter and remove bean of ObjectMapper.
Check answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51149932/9833606

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem is I pass LocalDateTime at requestParam, but I using ObjectMapper which only work with request's body.

And to resolve my issue I create new component LocalDateTimeConverter and remove bean of ObjectMapper.

```
@Component
public class LocalDateTimeConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDateTime> {
private final DateTimeFormatter formatter;

@Autowired
public LocalDateTimeConverter(@Value("${dateTime.format}") String dateTimeFormat) {
    this.formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimeFormat);
}

@Override
public LocalDateTime convert(String source) {
    if (source == null || source.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    return LocalDateTime.parse(source, formatter);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> class org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException

I think here you need to use *JsonSerializer* and *JsonDeserializer*.

So, when request comes you use *JsonDeserializer*, it will convert your date of String format to required Date format. Here is a code,

```
@Component
public class DateDeSerializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    public final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("date format");

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        if (jp.getCurrentToken().equals(JsonToken.VALUE_STRING)) {
            try {
                return formatter.parse(jp.getText());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // throw exception 
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Date> handledType() {
        return Date.class;
    }

}
```

To format your response use *JsonSerializer*. Here is a sample code,

```
@Component
public class DateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("date format");

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeObject(formatter.format(value));
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Date> handledType() {
        return Date.class;
    }

}
```